# Mysqli_insert_id не работает

Tags: php, mysql

Нужно получить айди последнего инсерта.

Делаю так:

```
запрос
$last = mysqli_insert_id();
```

Ласт возвращает пустоту.

Подключение к бд такое:

```
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost'); // MySQL Сервер
define('DB_USER', 'user'); // Пользователь Mysql
define('DB_PASS', 'pass'); // Пароль MySql
define('DB_BASE', 'db'); // База данных MySql
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8'); // Кодировка базы MySql (Стандартно utf8)
$connect_db = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASS,DB_BASE) or die('Ошибка подключения: '.mysqli_connect_error());
mysqli_set_charset ($connect_db, DB_CHARSET) or die('Кодировка не установлена');
```

Comment: Под `запрос` подразумевается `insert into...` ?

Comment: Да. Разобрался.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильно:

```
$last = mysqli_insert_id($connect_db);
```